# How to animate two value expression in mathematica

Tags: plotting, manipulate, animation

I have an expression which is a function of two variables. How to animate this?

```
m = 200;
y = Sin[\[Pi]*x]*Exp[I*m*t]
Manipulate[Plot[y, {x, 0, 1}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Well, you can't plot a complex number `Exp[I m t]`. You can plot its real or complex value or its magnitude. Which one you want to plot?

Comment: The question how to define `y` so it works it answered in the linked topic. What do you want to show is the question to you. Let me know if you disagree.

Comment: I want to Animate, how to use that

Comment: @acoustics `Animate` syntax is the same as for `Manipulate`.

Comment: \[Omega] = 200;
w2[t_] := Sin[\[Pi]*x]*Sin[\[Pi]*y]*(Cos[\[Omega]*t] + Sin[\[Omega]*t])
Manipulate[Plot3D[#, {t, 1, 10}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] &@w2[t]

Comment: I followed the post I edited my code , still not working

Comment: Please read the topic linked at the top of that post. You need to pass `x` and `y` as well.